# Adding two values in a select statement where one of the values is coming from a function - codeigniter/php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have a function that is returning one result "3" and i have another main function that is making a query to the database and within the select statement i need the value to be added to the select statement.

This query returns the one value from the first function:

```
function insert() {
$siteid = 1;
$field = 3;
$time = "2011-10-11 15:04:56";
$this->db->select('Offset_value', 1)
     ->from('offset')
     ->where('siteid', $siteid)
     ->where('Offset_field', $field)
     ->where('time <', $time);
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

foreach ($query as $row) {
    echo $row['Offset_value'];
    }
return $query;

}
```

Then i need that to calculate in this select statement:

```
$this->db->select("kwh * $dr * $kwp + $this->insert() AS kwhdata")
         ->from('expected_kwh')
         ->where('direction', $direction)
         ->where('tilt', $tilt)
         ->where('month', $month);
    $query2 = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    return $query2;
```

I'm trying to rewrite a stored procedure that was created in mssql and this is how it works there so i'm trying to use the same approach here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think php just doesn't like the $obj->method syntax inside quotes. Try this for that select line:

```
$this->db->select("kwh * $dr * $kwp + ".$this->insert()." AS kwhdata")
```